# How to access an svg element's inner html in javacscript and change it?

Tags: html, svg

My goal is to access the text displayed on the svg element (the inner html of the svg text attribute) , then replace it with what the user enters through the prompt. Here is my code

```js
function display_name_submission_form(event) {
 var name = prompt("please enter the name for this seat");
 if (name != null) {
  event.target.setAttribute('fill', 'url(#gradRed)');
  document.getElementById('seat1_details').textContent = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <svg height="1000" width="1000">
 <g>
  <defs>
   <lineargradient id="gradGreen" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(152, 251, 152);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 128, 0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
   </lineargradient>
   <lineargradient id="gradYellow" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255, 140, 0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(218, 165, 32);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
   </lineargradient>
   <lineargradient id="gradRed" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255, 0, 0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(178, 34, 34);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
   </lineargradient>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="70" cy="200" fill="url(#gradGreen)" id="seat1" onclick="display_name_submission_form(event)" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></circle>
  <text fill="#black" font-family="Verdana" font-size="30" id="seat1_details" x="38" y="210">
   SVG
  </text>
 </g></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked for me in chrome

Comment: Maybe it has to do something with how the onclick is caused by clicking on the shape not the text? Is it possible to have a text element within an svg circle element?

Comment: Can you update your code to reflect what your local code looks like?

Comment: updated my local code in the post above. I'm using code pen to code. Do you recommend another way that is easy to test code?

Comment: Why is the script inside the svg? No need that I see. I’ll take a look when I get to s computer later today

Comment: I was experimenting with something, but I fixed that in the updated code. And thanks, looking forward to it.

Comment: figured it out. thank you.

Comment: See my answer for a better solution. I reopened since after all there were more complexities than immediately obvious when you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an event listener on the document and test what was clicked, button or text or something else

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var id = e.target.id;
  if (id != "seat1" && id != "seat1_details") return;
  var name = prompt("please enter the name for this seat");
  if (name != null) {
    document.getElementById("seat1").setAttribute('fill', 'url(#gradRed)');
    document.getElementById('seat1_details').textContent = name;
  }
});
```

```html
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <g>
    <defs>
      <lineargradient id="gradGreen" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(152, 251, 152);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0, 128, 0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
      </lineargradient>
      <lineargradient id="gradYellow" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255, 140, 0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(218, 165, 32);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
      </lineargradient>
      <lineargradient id="gradRed" x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="0%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255, 0, 0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(178, 34, 34);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
      </lineargradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="70" cy="200" fill="url(#gradGreen)" id="seat1"  r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></circle>
    <text fill="#black" font-family="Verdana" font-size="30" id="seat1_details" x="38" y="210">SVG</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```